# How do I get the missing coordinate to make my line perpendicular to the other line?

Tags: javascript

[image: Scenario]

Scenario 1
line 1: (x = 102, y = 370), (x = 890, y = 182)
line 2: (x = ?, y = 34), (x = ?, y = 596)

Scenario 2
line 1: (x = 102, y = 370), (x = 890, y = 182)
line 2: (x = 562, y = ?), (x = 611, y = ?)

Scenario 3
line 1: (x = 102, y = 370), (x = 890, y = 182)
line 2: (x = 562, y = ?), (x = ?, y = 596)

Scenario 4
line 1: (x = 102, y = 370), (x = 890, y = 182)
line 2: (x = ?, y = 24), (x = 611, y = 596)

Here is my current code:

```
function getPoint(coor1_line1, coor2_line1, coor1_line2){

    var x1 = parseInt(coor1_line1.coor_x), 
        y1 = parseInt(coor1_line1.coor_y), 
        x2 = parseInt(coor2_line1.coor_x), 
        y2 = parseInt(coor2_line1.coor_y), 
        x3 = parseInt(coor1_line2.coor_x), 
        y3 = parseInt(coor1_line2.coor_y);
    var px = x2-x1, 
        py = y2-y1, 
        dAB = px*px + py*py;
    var u = ((x3 - x1) * px + (y3 - y1) * py) / dAB;
    var x = x1 + u * px, y = y1 + u * py;
    return { 
        coor_x : x, 
        coor_y: y
    };

}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant?

Comment: Code can be PHP or javascript.

Comment: Do you need a formula? Does a graphic with a soltion how to calculates help?

Comment: Yes, I need a formula to get the missing coordinates for the line to make it perpendicular to the other line.

Comment: I tried to come up with a formula, calculating a vector from the missing point to the other one. But I think it is not possible to determine the exact point, as you could set the vector to any point at y = 596 and it would always go to y = 34 with the same pitch.. I will think more about it

Comment: the other line has the negative reciprocal value of the slope. the points can be at any place.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand because your graph isn't on page with your current code. Current code suggests you know 3 points (with x,y coords of all three) whereas the graph suggests otherwise. So what is the correct one?

Comment: The current code is for the Scenario 4 line 1: (x = 102, y = 370), (x = 890, y = 182) line 2: (x = ?, y = 24), (x = 611, y = 596) where three coordinates is determine. And the return of the function is for the fourth coordinates.

Comment: @JohnFernando As I mentioned in my answer, if you set one X coordinate to a value, then you can calculate the other one as explained below. It would be 611-134.08 and that’s the other X value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several commented, there's not a single solution. But we can express the solution set. My maths are a bit rusty, I hope the following is correct:

Let name (AB) the first line with known A and B, and (CD) the second, where we know y(C) and y(D).

We can determine (AB) slope: m = (y(B)-y(A))/(x(B)-x(A))
The perpendicular slope, so the one of (CD), is m' = -1/m
And you can also express m' in function of C and D coordinates. So matching the two expressions together, you are able to express x(D) in function of x(C), which gives you the set of solutions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I say it is unsolvable to determine the exact points in your graphic. I calculated the vector from one missing point to another. That is possible with the help of being orthogonal to the other vector. However, the vector you get at the end, can start at any position at X with `y = 596` and will always meet every criteria (as long `x` is bigger or equals than `102` and less or equals than `890`). It will cross the other path and be orthogonal and will end at `y= 34`. You can try to approximate a solution, but you can not determine the correct points in your graphic.

That is my calculation for the vector.

[image]

`BA` is the vector from one unkown point to the other one (in my example from B to A). You know that (x-a) is 134,08 and you could approximate it with setting one x to a value and then calculate the other one.